# Sending msg via RS232 every 5 minutes in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, delay

I am wondering how to send msg using serialport every x minutes. In the meantime app should be fully accessible. I just want to check printer status, so i'm sending every 5 minutes "Error status request" and if there are some errors - then sound alarm or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: This should help me with my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the serial port using c# fairly easily

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

The simplest way to perform an action every x minutes is to spawn a thread off and put in a loop which performs Thread.Sleep(30000). You need to build some control code in so that you can stop your thread from the main code

Comment: Using a full Thread and Sleep() is silly. Just use a Timer (it will run on the ThreadPool).